# How to specify the precision params with a String in BigDecimal constructor?

Tags: ruby, bigdecimal

The `BigDecimal` constructor take an optional second params which specify the precision digits of the object. from [ruby-doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-c-new):

> new(initial, digits)
>
> The number of significant digits, as a Fixnum. If
>   omitted or 0, the number of significant digits is determined from the
>   initial value.

However, when working with the String, this behavior doesn't match the description.

```
BigDecimal.new('1.2345', 4).to_s('F')
# 1.2345
BigDecimal.new('1.2345', 1).to_s('F')
# 1.2345
```

How to specify the precision with BigDecimal when working with a String param?

Comment: how you got the output as `# 1.2345` ? I am seeing `#<BigDecimal:8701964,'0.12345E1',18(18)>` for `BigDecimal.new('1.2345', 4)`.

Comment: Use, `to_s('F')` to print it in float format.

Comment: You should show that in your post, as you are doing more than what you are explicitly saying and then saying you are confused, when what you show is not what you are doing to get the results.

Answer (score 3):

BigDecimal does not take precision param with string value.

**Right Approach:**

```
BigDecimal.new("1020.567").round(2) => 1020.57
```

**Wrong Approach:**

```
BigDecimal.new(1020.567, 2) => 1000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround would be `BigDecimal.new('1.2345'.to_f, 1)`